# Disk failures oddity but SMART data doesn't appear to show anything dubious

Tags: disk, smart

I've had three disk failures in the past ten days but when I look at the SMART data for the disc there's nothing particularly noteworthy (or so it seems to me).
The entries in SYSLOG are of the type

```
Jul  5 12:59:28 hp-64 kernel: [ 5123.303656] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
Jul  5 12:59:28 hp-64 kernel: [ 5123.303671] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 15 c5 48 70 00 00 08 00
Jul  5 12:59:28 hp-64 kernel: [ 5123.303678] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 365250672
Jul  5 12:59:28 hp-64 kernel: [ 5123.303689] EXT4-fs warning (device sda7): ext4_end_bio:330: I/O error -5 writing to inode 7616777 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 45656335)
Jul  5 12:59:28 hp-64 kernel: [ 5123.303695] Buffer I/O error on device sda7, logical block 31739918
```

and more similar. It then sets /home (that's where the errors occur) into R/O mode although, and in my opinion annoyingly, it doesn't actually issue any notification simply lets me infer from that fact that I cannot save files etc. that something is amiss. I then ran fsck (actually after rebooting) and fixed various errors (I have the list of the inodes etc) and then it works again.

I've run the SMART short test, it say 'passed' and as far as I understand them the values in the SMART data are not indicative of any real problems and for almost all the 'worst' is the same as the 'normalized' figure. The temperatures are not particularly high in the machine (currently 31 deg C).

The sectors reported as causing the failure are not numerically contiguous, or even particularly close (but then I'm not sure how the numbering relates to the physical media).

I noticed that the first two failures occurred immediately after a software update but for numbers 2 and 3 the errors occurred when I accessed Thunderbird (and that probably was the case for the first); not that I'm suggesting that the software has any relevance to the errors. Debugfs does show that the inodes that were mentioned in the messages are in the TB mailbox (I've only checked for the second failure).
I will probably run the longer SMART test when once I've sent this so it may find something useful, or not.

Does anyone have any suggestions or comments ?

The disc is a WDC WD500 GB which has been in use for three years (SMART says powered on for under 6 months) although it was bought, and remained in its sealed packet, a couple of years before. I'm running Xubuntu 16.04LTS. And it's in a HP Microserver.

Just to add a little more information: about two weeks earlier I had a hard failure on an older Seagate 7200.12 250GB disc in the same machine and I now have a 1TB WD disc waiting to install. I thought that the Seagate may have been a victim of the firmware BSY bug and tried the remedies but it was giving 11 clicks on spin up which seemed to suggest a permanent seek error and it is still dead. I cannot believe that this is relevant, however, but it only indicates my level of annoyance at the moment !

Your comments are welcome

added Smart results:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE

    1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
    3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   142   114   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3891
    4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1399
    5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
    7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
    9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       4346
   10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
   11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
   12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1399
  192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
  193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   173   173   000    Old_age   Always       -       83009
  194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   123   107   000    Old_age   Always       -       20
  196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

And the 'extended' test 'completed without error'

graham

Comment: SMART is not the only indicator of disk failure, unfortunately.  Relying solely on the SMART data to determine if the disk is dead/dying is not the best idea.  Can you perhaps share the specific SMART values you're getting, though?

Comment: SMART just guesses. If you need accurate dats loss predictions, take error scanning on optical drives.

Comment: Your multiple failures might indicate a power spike.  When did you last change your surge protectors?  They do have a lifetime, and after a known spike, consider replacing them.

Comment: Smart data after the test added. As for power: this is through a UPS although I've never been able to get linux to understand the data from the UPS so I have no voltage logs etc.

Comment: Out of interest I've just had another failure, same type as above, and this time it was a couple of days after upgrading to Xubuntu 18.04